# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1'

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that appear only in chrome and working fine in firefox without no problem

```
      computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element, ':before');
      content = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('content').slice(1, -1);
      // content --> NULL
      matchResult = content.match(/^\s*(\d+)(?:\s?\.(.+))?\s*$/);
      if (matchResult) {
        numberOfColumns = matchResult[1];
        columnClasses = ((_ref = matchResult[2]) != null ? _ref.split('.') : void 0) || ['column'];
      } else {
        matchResult = content.match(/^\s*\.(.+)\s+(\d+)\s*$/);
        columnClasses = matchResult[1];    // <-- Error here
        numberOfColumns = (_ref1 = matchResult[2]) != null ? _ref1.split('.') : void 0;
      }
      return {
        numberOfColumns: numberOfColumns,
        columnClasses: columnClasses
      };
    };
    add_columns = function(grid, items) {
      var columnClasses, columnsFragment, columnsItems, i,
```

and The error in the console is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`

Comment: can show the line with this the erorr is displaying.

Comment: It might be more useful to show a self-contained piece of code rather than just grabbing some lines.

Comment: Sorry i pointed to the error in a comment line

Comment: Probably `matchResult` is `null`… How can you be sure that the second regex does always match?

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
if (matchResult) {
    numberOfColumns = matchResult[1];
    columnClasses = ((_ref = matchResult[2]) != null ? _ref.split('.') : void 0) || ['column'];
} else if (matchResult = content.match(/^\s*\.(.+)\s+(\d+)\s*$/)){
    columnClasses = matchResult[1];    // <-- Error here
    numberOfColumns = (_ref1 = matchResult[2]) != null ? _ref1.split('.') : void 0;
} else {
    columnClasses = numberOfColumns = null;
}
// ...
```

Make sure the `matchResult` isn't null before process the data.